# Javascript Fetch API PUT Request

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, react-redux, fetch

I want to update the book ratings. User will submit rating for a particular book through a form.
*postRatings* is an action creator which is dispatched to component with the form. *Books* variable
contains the same book object as present in the json file. The rating gets updated for the specific book  in the *Books* variable and then I want to delete the older object and put this updated object. But when I try to do this, I get **404: Not Found** error message. It would be great if someone can point out where am I mistaking and help me solve this error.

JSON File (Fake Rest API made using json-server Node Module):

```
{
  "books": [
    {
      "id": "0",
      "title": "1984",
      "author": "George Orwell",
      "rating": "4.6",
      "points: "228",
      "total": "50
    },
    {
      "id": "1",
      "title": "To Kill a Mockingbird",
      "author": "Harper Lee",
      "rating": "4.8",
      "points: "241",
      "total": "50
    }
  ]
}
```

postRatings Action Creator:

```
export const postRatings = (Books, title, rating) => (dispatch) => {  
  Books.some(function(obj){
    if(obj.title==title) {
      obj.total = parseInt(obj.total)+1;
        let newPts = parseInt(obj.points) + parseInt(rating);
        obj.points = ""+newPts;
        let newRating = (parseInt(obj.points) + parseInt(rating)) / parseFloat(obj.total);
        obj.ratings = ""+Math.floor(newRating * Math.pow(10, 1)) / Math.pow(10, 1).toFixed(1);
        return true;
    }   
  });
  fetch('localhost:3001/books', {
    method: 'PUT',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(Books)
  })
  .then(response => {
    if(response.ok) {
      return response;
    } else {
        var error = new Error('Error- ' + response.status + ":" + response.statusText);
        error.response = response;
        throw error;
    }
  },
  error => {
    var errmess = new Error(error.message);
    throw errmess;
  })
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(response => {console.log("response:"+JSON.stringify(response)); alert("Rating Added!")})
  .catch(error => {console.log('Error Message: '+ error.message)
    alert("Some Problem Occurred.\nError: "+error.message);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to include the id of the object that you want to update. see the [default route of json-server](https://github.com/typicode/json-server#routes)

so in your fetch url, add the book id at the end of the route

```
fetch(`localhost:3001/books/${Books.id}`)
```

Comment: Ahh! this solved the problem. I was trying to update the entire book object instead of a particular book. I missed the plural routes for PUT too. Thanks for helping me out :-)

Comment: @KevalDhanani You're welcome. Glad I could help